# Getting npm err E404 while installing unicons for react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I'm creating a weather-app project using create-react-app and I was installing unicons for the project , but it is showing npm error. I tried few solutions but didn't work.

This is the command for unicons react installation

```
npm install --save @iconscout/react-unicons~
```

This is the result I got

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@iconscout%2Freact-unicons~ - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@iconscout/react-unicons~@*' is not in this registry.     
npm ERR! 404 This package name is not valid, because
npm ERR! 404  1. name can no longer contain special characters ("~'!()*")npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Saqlain\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-02-12T19_10_00_477Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: remove the tilde `-`

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@iconscout/react-unicons

Answer (score -2):

Using VPN pointing separate region might overcome this issue.And for another fact this works if you try to access from US region via a VPN connection.Try this and see.